# Proving equivalence on a general case study

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I need some help proving this because i couldn't reach the form the exercise asks for

to simplify the exercise we take that all fractions are defined \
Let $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ be two sequences defined by their first terms
$u_0$ , $v_0$ $\in \mathbb{R}$
and the following relation $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$
 \begin{cases}
  u_{n+1}=\alpha u_n + \beta v_n \\
  v_{n+1} = \lambda u_n + \mu v_n 
 \end{cases}
 $$
let $(a_n)$ and be a sequence defined $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ as follows :
$$
  a_n = p_1 u_n + q_1 v_n 
 $$

prove the following equivalence
\begin{cases}
   p_1 = \dfrac{\mu - \lambda}{\alpha \mu - \beta \lambda} \\
   q_1 = \dfrac{\alpha - \beta}{\alpha \mu - \beta \lambda}
  \end{cases}
equivalent to $(a_n)$ being cosntant

all i've done is calculating $$a_{n+1}=(\alpha p_1 + \lambda q_1)u_n + (\beta p_1 + \mu q_1)v_n$$ and also having $$a_n = p_1 u_n + q_1 v_n$$
so for $(a_n)$ to be constant we must get $ a_{n+1} = a_n$ therefore :
$$(\alpha p_1 + \lambda q_1)u_n + (\beta p_1 + \mu q_1)v_n = p_1 u_n + q_1 v_n$$
and from here i don't know what to go for